# Populate custom field on publish or update

Tags: php

I have a custom post type called **books**, with fields genre, author, and bookname. I want to dynamically create a link called "booklink" (custom field) based on the data in the 3 above fields, and put "booklink" into the database for the post on publish or update.

How do I do it?

My code:

```
<?php    
$genre = get_field('genre');
$bookname=get_field('bookname');
$author=get_field('author);
$booklink="http://mybooks/".$genre."/".$author."/".$bookname.".com";
?>
```

I don't know how to get this "booklink" field created, and updated with the data, in the database for each post on publish/update. I'd like to retrieve the "booklink" directly, instead of generating it each time for the post_type books.

Please guide.

**Changed code to elaborate more**

Using the code by **passatgt**, I tried the following :-

```
function update_bookstore_field( $post_id ) {
    if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'books' ) {

        $booklist = get_field('booklist'); 
        foreach ($booklist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
            if (!empty($post)) {
                $bookstore=array();
                $bookstore[] = strip_tags(get_field('bookstore',$post)); 
            } 
        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();  
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bookstore', $bookstore[0] );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_bookstore_field' );
```

Where booklist is a post type connected as a post object to books, based on the selection of the book in the booklist, the custom field bookstore in post type = books is filled with corresponding bookstore of booklist post type.

e.g.

```
booklist        bookstore
--------        ---------
Wiz of Oz       Amazon
Wiz of Oz 1     Flipkart
Wiz of Oz 2     Barnes&Noble
```

So if in the select field of books post type, "Wiz of Oz 1" is selected in the booklist,  then the bookstore in books should be populated with flipkart automatically on clicking publish or update... that's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using advanced custom fields, correct? Not sure if ACF will pick up the fields without the $post_id set as the second parameter for get_field, so i changed your code to include the post id.

```
function update_booklink_field( $post_id ) {
    if ( 'book' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
         $genre = get_field('genre',$post_id);
         $bookname=get_field('book name',$post_id);
         $author=get_field('author',$post_id);
         $booklink="http://mybooks/".$genre."/".$author."/".$bookname.".com";
         update_post_meta( $post_id, 'booklink', $booklink );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field' );
```

The "save_post" action will run on publish and on post edit.

Comment: where should i put this code?

Comment: in your theme's functions.php file

Comment: ...thanx .....can u help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587118/post-link-set-new-link-as-permalink-in-the-code too plz

Comment: ok i tired the code but when i reopen the post the custom field booklink already by acf is still empty it doesn't have the link.